# Responsive CSS for Bootstrap Thumbnail & Caption classes

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Rails, Bootstrap and Imagemagick for a marketplace app.

I have a thumbnail grid where the images uploaded are of different aspect ratios. Images are resized to thumbnails by imagemagick to fit within a 200x200 space.

Here is a screenshot of what I get using bootstrap classes.

[image]

How do I get the caption to align consistently and responsively - I want the first line of the product title for each product to be in the same line and the thumbnail boxes to all be the same size i.e. images centered within a portion of the thumbnail box and then the caption underneath.

Here is my html.erb:

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="row">
    <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail" > 
         <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive aspect"), listing %>
            <div class="caption">
              <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
              <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.caption {

  h3 {
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 2px;
  }

  p {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  }

}
```

I tried using fixed pixel containers but those are not responsive.

Comment: Images are resized to thumbnails by imagemagick to fit within a 200x200 space. I don't quite understand Why they have different height?

Comment: I'm using imagemagick's HxW resize option i.e 200x200. But that resizes either height or width to a max of 200. So if I have an image 500X600, it resizes to 167x200, which causes the caption to misalign. Is there another imagemagick option I can use. That would be a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the caption and the thumbnail separately into a div (icon).  Use margin-right and margin-left auto to center.  You may have to put a br in between the thumbnail and caption divs if they are aligned with inline-block.

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="row">
    <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="thumbnail" > 
                    <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive aspect"), listing %>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
                    <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

.thumnbnail {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.caption {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.caption p {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.caption h3 {
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

Comment: You don't use "icon" in your css?